# Scraping data from website

Tags: python, python-2.7, web-scraping, html-parsing, beautifulsoup

I'm facing problem in linking the links together. i need spider code who interlinks the links on the pages and grab me the required details until now my code is able to grab the required information but there are other pages too so i need other pages information too link the base_url contains the applications info then i want to collect all the links from that page and  then want to switch next page and repeat the same thing then i need to collect the each application details like their names, version no etc from the links i have been collected
so right now im able to collect all the information only links are not inter linked how i can do that help me out..... here is my code:

```
#extracting links
def linkextract(soup): 
    print "\n extracting links of next pages"
    print "\n\n page 2 \n"
        sAll = [div.find('a') for div in soup.findAll('div', attrs={'class':''})]
        for i in sAll:
            suburl = ""+i['href'] #checking pages
        print suburl
        pages = mech.open(suburl)
        content = pages.read()
        anosoup = BeautifulSoup(content)
        extract(anosoup)
    app_url = ""
    print app_url
    #print soup.prettify()
    page1 = mech.open(app_url)
    html1 = page1.read()
    soup1 = BeautifulSoup(html1)
    print "\n\n application page details \n"
    extractinside(soup1)
```

assistance required thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Here's what you should start with:

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = 'http://www.pcwelt.de/download-neuzugaenge.html'

soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen(URL))
links = [tr.td.a['href'] for tr in soup.find('div', {'class': 'boxed'}).table.find_all('tr') if tr.td]

for link in links:
    url = "http://www.pcwelt.de{0}".format(link)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen(url))

    name = soup.find('span', {'itemprop': 'name'}).text
    version = soup.find('td', {'itemprop': 'softwareVersion'}).text
    print "Name: %s; Version: %s" % (name, version)
```

prints:

```
Name: Ashampoo Clip Finder HD Free; Version: 2.3.6
Name: Many Cam; Version: 4.0.63
Name: Roboform; Version: 7.9.5.7
...
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: yeah need this but i want to switch to next page also then do the same process above u explained.

Comment: else i need to collect the whole page tables data this one collecting the only a single table

Comment: @user3387184 got it, but I've intentionally just provided a step in the right direction.

Comment: @user3387184 and, by the way, [Scrapy](http://scrapy.org/) looks more suitable for the task.

Comment: I just need to know hwo i can switch to next pages else every thing is done. I need to put an extra effort again for scrapy to learn it